# url image upload from db by session to page not always work

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am trying to load a picture by the `url(image location)` but encountered with strange problem; sometimes the image loads, but after refresh not... If I go to the image location (url) and back and press refresh again I can load image again. Is this about size or is it the the sites? or maybe another problem?

```
<div class="ato"  id="firstone" 
    style="width: 960px; height: 320px; margin: 0 auto; 
    border-radius:30px; border-color: #B0832A; border-width: 2px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    background-image: url(<%= Response.Write(Session("imagelink")) %>); 
    background-size: 1000px 350px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
</div>
```

and if I already here is anyone knows how in the case of background image I can add an default image in case of not found?

ANSWER:
I FOUND a way. no need for further debate :) 
apparently it was  solved when i change the location of the url image.just to use third side site to upload image and give usable link to it(stable one). there are many host image sites that provide option to store images and give proper working for a long term and **stable** links to the images. in my case postimage.org 
i believe that the problem was unstable links(url) , some site protect and even block,the connection and each site option whenever share picture or not.

Comment: If you are familiar with using the chrome developer console you can look at the network stack and find out why this image is not loading.  Are you getting a 404 error meaning the image is not there?

Comment: the size of the image might not have much to do with it, if the images are showing up when you go to the urls directly.  Either your urls are not formulated properly or the image is probably not available on the server.  Are you using any server side code to process the image?

Comment: ALL I DO IS TO SAVE THE URL LINK OF THE IMAGE IN DATA BASE AND UPLOAD AFTERWORDS BY SESSION LINK IN IMAGE/BACKGROUND IMAGE. I DID NOTICED THAT SOME IMAGES ALWAYS UPLOADED BUT OTHERS FROM OTHER SITES NOT ALWAYS. AND NO IT SHOW NO 404 ERROR AND THE IMAGE IS THERE.